# python sockets how to not queue connection requests

Tags: python, sockets

This is the code I have:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(0)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
sock.bind(('localhost',self._lp))
sock.listen(0)
```

for the listen(), I have tried 0 and 1 but in both cases once one client connects, future clients will hang until the first connects. I would like any additional clients that attempt to connect to fail instead of waiting.  Presently, the only thing I can think of is to periodically check sock and    close any queued connections. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound trivial, but: 
Close the listening socket -- that will stop it from listening!

```
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) to automatically close it after use.

```
# Note that the arguments were removed -- they were already the defaults
with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.setblocking(0)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(("localhost", self._lp))
    sock.listen(0)
```